# How to access global variable after setInterval function. variables gives undefined or NaN even after it is set

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, timer, setinterval

This is a typescript class. I am trying to access the starttime & count in setInterval function. I have set the values before,why do we get undefined and NaN in it? and how do I solve this issue?

```
startTimer() {
 this.startTime = new Date();
 this.count = 100;
 console.log("STARTTIME: " + this.startTime); //RESULT: Mon Dec 17..etc
 console.log("COUNT: " + this.count); //RESULT: 100
    this.timer = setInterval(function () {
      console.log("STARTTIME: " + this.startTime); //Undefined
      this.count += 1;
      console.log("COUNT: " + this.count); //NaN
     }, 1000);
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using [fat arrow](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html) instead of function

(from the docs)

> `this` has traditionally been a pain point in JavaScript. As a wise man once said "I hate JavaScript as it tends to lose the meaning of `this` all too easily". Fat arrows fix it by capturing the meaning of this from the surrounding context.

Therefore use it like this:

```
setInterval(() => {  // <-----
  console.log("STARTTIME: " + this.startTime); 
  this.count += 1;
  console.log("COUNT: " + this.count); 
}, 1000);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2jesg)

Comment: and how you are supposed to obtain the pointer of already initialize setInterval to clear it later?